# How to assign different column names within a list

Tags: r, list

I have a list with 15 data frames each have the following columns

```
> head(final_data[[1]])
      DateTime   Value
147 2013-03-01 2320.58
148 2013-04-01 2336.89
149 2013-05-01 2213.78
150 2013-06-01 2135.90
151 2013-07-01 2302.79
152 2013-08-01 2177.01
```

I want to change the name `"Value"` to a different name for all the dataframes such that the final names of the columns for these 15 dataframes must look like

```
names(final_data[[1]])
DateTime       A 

names(final_data[[2]])
DateTime      B
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to loop through the sequence of `list` and do the assignment

```
final_data2 <- lapply(seq_along(final_data), function(i) {
                                      d1 <- final_data[[i]]
                                       names(d1)[2] <- LETTERS[i]
                                       d1
            })
```

---

Or use `Map`

```
final_data2 <- Map(function(x,y) {names(x)[2] <- y; x}, final_data, LETTERS[1:15])
```